# How to add subclasses to an object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, subclass

I wonder how it would be possible to add subclasses to an object like I try to use in the code below.

The code is quite self explanatory for what I am trying to do. How can I add .id, .name and .lastname to an object?

```js
var obj = getObjfunction(); //Get object with all info in it and show in console
console.log(obj.id);
console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.lastname);

function getObjfunction() {

    var obj;

    //I like to set 3 subclass to this "obj" like below. How to achieve this?
    obj.id = 0;
    obj.name = "Tom";
    obj.lastname = "Smith";
}
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say `subclass`?

Comment: "add subclasses to an object" doesn't really make sense.

Comment: Subclass might be the wrong term in this case. The first answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028673/shorthand-for-object-create-with-multiple-properties/41028806#41028806

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you seem to be looking for is a constructor. You would call it with `new` and initialise it in the constructor by referencing `this`:

```js
var obj = new getObjfunction();
console.log(obj.id);
console.log(obj.name);
console.log(obj.lastname);

function getObjfunction() {
    this.id = 0;
    this.name = "Tom";
    this.lastname = "Smith";
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was exactly what I was after. That works great. Thank you!