# Can I simplify the instantiation of this constructor function?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to break down the following code (especially the `new` keyword) into simpler code (so I can understand what's going on)?:

```js
function F() {
  this.color = 'red';
  this.printNumber = function printNumber() {
    console.log(5);
  };
 }

 let o = new F();
 console.log(o);
```

Here is my attempt:

I thought I was onto a winner when I was told that `let o = new F();` is the same as `let o = F.call({})` but I can see on the console that the first additionally gives the empty object a `constructor` property set to the constructor function.

Is it very important that the new object has a constructor property set to the constructor function? I know that this constructor function would be considered a method and the `this` in there would refer to this object as a whole. Which leads me to think that the `new` works by:

1. Instantly creating an object that has a constructor property set to the constructor function.
2. Executing the constructor property (a method) so that the new object looks like:

```js
{
color: "red",
printNumber: printNumber,
constructor: F
//as it is an instance of the inbuilt Object constructor function, it has all the properties/methods of an object
}
```

Comment: This is what new really does:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new

Comment: Or you can use ES6 classes : `Class F { color= "red"; printNumber() { console.log(this.color); } }`

Comment: If this code works, and you want a review of the code, you should check the help center for [codereview.se] to see if it is on topic there.

Comment: @HereticMonkey This question would be off-topic on Code Review as it is missing context. In the future please link to the help center when recommending Code Review. Take, "This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there."

Comment: @Peilonrayz your example would help more in tick marks so that it can be copied and pasted. Note that I did say to check the help center, and all sites have their help centers at /help.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Good point about tick marks. Thank you I'll do that from now on. `This may be on-topic on Code Review. Please check [if it is on-topic](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [how to post a good question](//codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) before posting there.` Not all users know what or where the help center is, additionally it helps increase the number of users that check our rules rather than just clicking your link and the "ask question" button.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it very important that the new object has a constructor property
> set to the constructor function?

If your intention is to create an object that you can instantiate and inherit from, then yes, you should use the `new` syntax. [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) does just that, it *invokes* the function (runs its code) without formally instantiating an instance of the object. `call()` also allows you to define what `this` will bind to when the function runs, but `call()` and `new` are not the same.

When you instantiate with `new` an instance of the object is created and the constructor function executes. `this` is then bound to the new instance.

For more details on how `new` and prototypical inheritance works, see [this other post of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028673/shorthand-for-object-create-with-multiple-properties/41028806#41028806).

Also, fyi, you should add methods of your object (that operate the same no matter what particular instance you have) to the `prototype` of your object, not the object itself:

```js
function F() {
  this.color = 'red';
}

// Methods are usually added just once to the object's
// prototype and then all instances inherit it, which
// has a lower memory footprint because the method is
// defined and attached just once instead of on each 
// instance.
F.prototype.printNumber = function printNumber() {
    console.log(5);
};

let o = new F();
console.log(o.color);
o.printNumber();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call a constructor function with the `new` keyword, following things happen:

1. A new empty object is created and assigned to `this`.
2. The function body executes. Usually it modifies `this`, adds new properties to it.
3. The value of `this` is returned.

The return object has in its prototype the `constructor` property which references the constructor function.

Now why is the constructor function in the prototype is important? It's all about object inheritance pattern in JS.

```
//Here is the Animal constructor
function Animal() {
   this.live  = true;
}

//Object methods are attached to the prototype. So, they have a single presence in the object hierarchy
Animal.prototype.move = function() {console.log('moving')}; 


//Here is the Cat constructor. This is how JS makes the Cat inherit from the animal.
function Cat() {
   Animal.call(this);   //The this keyword points to the Cat object being created
}

//Let's set its prototype
Cat.prototype = new Animal();
Cat.prototype.constructor = Cat;


//All is set. Let's create the child object    
let cat = new Cat();
```

Here are the sequence of events.

1. The simple Animal constructor is declared. It will add `live=true` to every animal.
2. It's prototype has the `move` method. So, any animal can move and this move function will not be instantiated - because it is in the prototype - not in `this`.
3. Define the Cat constructor. It simple calls the `Animal` constructor without `new`. So, it will not create an Animal - but it will create all the animal properties in the resultant object.
4. Set an Animal as the prototype of the Cat. Notice that it inherits the Animals prototype methods - namely `move`. This is why we say javascript has prototypical inheritance.
5. Set the Cat constructor function to Cat. This is due to the fact that by point 4, the constructor function of the Cat too is Animal. We change it here. (yes - bizarre)
6. Create a new Cat. This will `call` the Animal constructor without `new`, so, the cat has all the Animal properties. The cat can move - because it's prototype has the `move` method. And finally, it't constructor function is Cat - so, the `new` keyword will use it.

---

The new Ecmascript versions wrap this all in `Class` and does things automatically. But I believe that the fundamental understanding is important too.