# Defining inheritance chain in JS - why recreate prototype?

Tags: javascript, oop

While reading through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance I saw that we should replace the `Teacher`'s prototype with a new one, which has its prototype set to `Person`:

```js
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Object.defineProperty(Teacher.prototype, 'constructor', { 
    value: Teacher, 
    enumerable: false, // so that it does not appear in 'for in' loop
    writable: true });
```

I'd rather do it this way, it seems more logical to me:

```js
Teacher.prototype.__proto__ = Person.prototype
```

As far as I understand, it ends up with the same result and the constructor stays correct, I do not have to replace it.

Is there any difference between MDN's approach and mine?

//EDIT
As @ Asutosh pointed out, MDN discourages from using `__proto__` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto). However, MDN also says to use `Object.setPrototypeOf` instead. So, can I do this:

```js
Object.setPrototypeOf(Teacher, Person.prototype)
```

instead of original

```js
Teacher.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype);
Object.defineProperty(Teacher.prototype, 'constructor', { 
    value: Teacher, 
    enumerable: false, // so that it does not appear in 'for in' loop
    writable: true });
```

Comment: __proto__ usage is deprecated in some manner. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @Asutosh That's interesting, thanks. Then, what about this, instead: `Object.setPrototypeOf(Teacher, Person.prototype)`

Comment: This is also discouraged.

Comment: Ahh, again :) Ok, I get it. However, I'm still just curious, would my proposed way of setting prototype break something (let's completely forget about the MDN's discouragement of doing it this way). I'm trying to understand how JS works.

Comment: No it does not break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I just do `Object.setPrototypeOf(Teacher, Person.prototype)`?

No, it would have to be

```
Object.setPrototypeOf(Teacher.prototype, Person.prototype);
```

Can you use that? Yes, it's totally fine, and basically equivalent to the `Object.create` + `.constructor` definition.

So why is this not the standard approach? Mostly because `Object.create` was available since ES5, and `Object.setPrototypeOf` only was introduced with ES6, but in ES6 we would just use `class Teacher extends Person` anyway.

Comment: @Loreno You might also be interested in [the even older pattern from ES3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12592913/what-is-the-reason-to-use-the-new-keyword-here) that worked in a similar manner to `Object.create`

Answer (score 1):

Remember that in JavaScript, a prototype isn't some concept of a future object (like a class) - - it's an actual instance that has state and behavior. Making a new instance isn't so much about inheritance as it is about the specific state of a particular instance.

If you don't create a new instance for the prototype, you can wind up with your new object sharing a specific prototype instance with other unintended object instances. Changes to that specific instance's state would immediately affect your object as well.

By setting the prototype to a new instance of an object, you gain access to the correct inheritance chain, but with a new, clean instance that isn't being shared with any other implementation.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028673/shorthand-for-object-create-with-multiple-properties/41028806#41028806) for more.