# JS: Why do you need to reset the constructor back after inheriting another prototype?

Tags: javascript

In the example below, why is `Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog`  needed?  I under we use:
`Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)` to inherit the `sayAnimal()` and any other functions added to the `Animal` prototype but how does that effect the constructor?  What would leaving it out do?

```
function Animal(gender) {
    this.gender = gender;
}

Animal.prototype.sayAnimal = function() {
    return "I am an animal"
}

function Dog(gender, barkSound) {
    Animal.call(this, gender)
    this.barkSound = barkSound
}

Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype) 

Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog
```

Comment: If you're doing this, I recommend you use `class` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Users of classes will expect the `.constructor` property of instances to refer to the constructor of that instance. For example:

```js
class ExtendedArray extends Array {
}

const e = new ExtendedArray();
console.log(e.constructor === ExtendedArray);
```

If you're using `function`s and extending manually, then if you don't set the constructor property on the subclass prototype explicitly, the `.constructor` will refer not to the subclass constructor (as a user of the code would usually expect), but to the superclass:

```js
function Animal(gender) {
}
function Dog(gender, barkSound) {
    Animal.call(this, gender)
}
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)

// oops, this refers to Animal...
console.log(Dog.prototype.constructor);
```

That said, it *probably* isn't an issue in most situations.

Comment: thanks.  At first, I thought it would create problems creating new instances of `Dog` but since `Dog` uses `Dog.constructor`, that hasn't changed...what would be using `Dog.prototype.constructor` ?

Comment: The user of an instance, when it's not sure what it's an instance of. It can use the `.constructor` property of the instance to get to the constructor function. This situation is extremely unusual in my experience, I've never encountered a need for it (outside of silly things like JS trivia questions)

Answer (score 0):

```
Dog.prototype = Object.create(Animal.prototype)
```

Causes the **entire** `prototype` object to be replaced with a new instance of `Animal.prototype`, which is important so that you don't start off with an `Animal.prototype` instance that has been altered from the original definition. At this point, if you were to create a new `Dog`, the `Animal` constructor would fire off and you wouldn't gain any of the characteristics of a `Dog` in your new instance, you'd just have another `Animal`.

But, when you add this:

```
Dog.prototype.constructor = Dog
```

You are only replacing the constructor portion of the  `Animal.prototype`, so that now when you create a new `Dog`, you are making a new instance of an `Animal` first, but with the `Dog` constructor, so that your `Animal` can be enhanced and worked with as a more specific type.

**I've written a bit more about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41028673/shorthand-for-object-create-with-multiple-properties/41028806#41028806).**